# Writing List to CSV in Python

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I'm writing data from a PDF to a CSV. The CSV needs to have one column, with each word on a separate row.

The code below writes each word on a separate row, but also puts each letter in a separate cell.

```
with open('annualreport.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    for i in keywords:
        write.writerow(i)
```

I have also attempted the following, which writes all the words to one row, with each word in a separate column:

```
with open('annualreport.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerow(keywords)
```

Comment: What is `keywords` ?

Comment: are you sure `keyword` is a list of strings? looks like more that is a single string

Comment: What is value is denoted by the variable ```keywords```? please provide full snippets of coder rather than just the part which gave error it helps alot

Comment: Please also provide a snippet of the result if possible

Comment: `writerow` treats the argument as an iterable and writes its elements as a row. If you want to write each word as one-element row - just change to `write.writerow([i])`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) expects an array. Thus a word is treated as an array with the individual letters **-> each letter is written into a new cell.**

Putting the value into a single array should fix the problem:

```py
with open('annualreport.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    for i in keywords:
        write.writerow( [ i ] ) # <-- before: write.writerow(i)
```

Comment: This works, but also adds a blank row between each word. Any idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv 

# data to be written row-wise in csv fil 
data = [['test'], [try], ['goal']] 
# opening the csv file in 'w+' mode 
file = open('output.csv', 'w+', newline ='') 

# writing the data into the file 
with file:     
    write = csv.writer(file) 
    write.writerows(data)
```